# Windows Authentication pops up multiple times for asp.net app with asp.net app in IFrame for Ipad

Tags: asp.net, safari, windows-authentication

This is the scenario:
An intranet application built with ASP.NET using integrated windows authentication.
On the start page of this application there is another ASP.NET application embedded in an IFrame which also uses integrated windows authentication. This is no problem for IE users but when iPad users connect to the site with Safari, the authentication pops up two times which is pretty annoying for the users. Is it possible to "share" the first authentication attempt with the other app so that iPad users only need to authenticate once?

Comment: Obligatory comment: its the iPad users' own fault for accessing a Windows based system on a non Windows device

Comment: It should nevertheless work without having to enter the same credentials two times in a row, plus, like it or not, people just love to use their iPad for everything it was never designed to do...